# Torque 3D building Template project yields "nfd.h file not found" error is VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, build, torque3d

I cloned the earliest release of Torque 3D here: [Github - Torque3D](https://github.com/GarageGames/Torque3D)
. I generated an "Empty" template project with the Project Manager tool and then started VS2013 Professional to get into the build-process.

Within VS I simply started the build solution like the tutorial tells me to do.

*But sadly there occurs an error:*

```
Fehler  101 error C1083: Datei (Include) kann nicht geöffnet werden: "nfd.h": No such file or directory c:\...\torque3d\engine\source\platform\nativedialogs\filedialog.cpp 32  1   T3D_Tutorial DLL
```

*I looked for that file and found it here:*

```
C:\...\Torque3D\Engine\lib\nativeFileDialogs\include\nfd.h
```

The file which throws this errors has following include statements:

```
#include "console/simBase.h"
#include "platform/nativeDialogs/fileDialog.h"
#include "platform/threads/mutex.h"
#include "core/util/safeDelete.h"
#include "math/mMath.h"
#include "core/strings/unicode.h"
#include "console/consoleTypes.h"
#include "platform/profiler.h"
#include "console/engineAPI.h"
#include <nfd.h> // badboy
#include "core/strings/stringUnit.h"
#include "core/frameAllocator.h"
```

I changed the include to: `#include "nativeFileDialogs/include/nfd.h` because I thought I was a clever boy and found the dependency where it really is - but sadly this smart action resulted in a even bigger mess:

```
Fehler  133 error LNK1120: 1 nicht aufgelöste Externe   C:\Users\Falke\Google Drive\Workspace.cloud\Software Development\Torque3DTryout\Torque3D\My Projects\T3D_Tutorial\game\T3D_Tutorial_DEBUG DLL.dll   T3D_Tutorial DLL
```

and

```
Fehler  132 error LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""public: void __thiscall Component::setOwner(class Entity *)" (?setOwner@Component@@QAEXPAVEntity@@@Z)" in Funktion ""public: bool __thiscall Entity::addComponent(class Component *)" (?addComponent@Entity@@QAE_NPAVComponent@@@Z)".    C:\...\Torque3D\My Projects\T3D_Tutorial\buildFiles\VisualStudio 2012\projects\entity.obj   T3D_Tutorial DLL
```

(sorry for the german translation - I did not managed to change the language settings while writing this question)

Answer (score 1):

1. remove nfd.h include.
2. gui/editor/inspector/mountingGroup.cpp and remove T3D/entity.h include.
3. remove TD3/entity.h and entity.cpp from project.
4. go to engine/TD3 directory and delete entity.h and entity.cpp.
5. build and fun.